# Contacts First and Last name along with email id details in android

Tags: android

I am using the following code to retrieve the contacts first and last name list from android however i also want to retrieve the email simultaneously:

```
Cursor1 = getContentResolver().query(
           public List<String> getFullContactName()
           {
                List<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
                String[] projection = new String[] {Data.DATA2, Data.DATA3};
                String where = Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'";
                Uri uri = Data.CONTENT_URI;

                ContentResolver contentResolver = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
                Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri,projection,where,null,null);
                String firstName, lastName;
                while (cursor.moveToNext())
                {
                    firstName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Data.DATA2));
                    lastName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Data.DATA3));
                    name.add(firstName + " " + lastName);     
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "First name"+firstName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Second name"+lastName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                cursor.close();
                cursor = null;
               return name;
            }
Cursor emails = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId, null, null); 
   while (emails.moveToNext()) { 
      // This would allow you get several email addresses 
      String emailAddress = emails.getString( 
      emails.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA)); 
   } 
   emails.close();
}
cursor.close();
```

I need to know how can i read first name ,last name email, phone number together using a single Cursor because i need to fetch details in a  list and then display them in a listview. I havent got a reference where i can fetch the details using a single cursor.

Comment: See my answer, it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code for get contact details.

```
public void getContacts(ContentResolver cr) {

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mContacts = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> mTempObj = new HashMap<String, String>();

    cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, null);
    cur.moveToFirst();
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < cur.getCount(); i++) {
            mTempObj.add("Email", cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA)));

            cur.moveToNext();
        }
    }

    cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, null);
    cur.moveToFirst();
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < cur.getCount(); i++) {
            mTempObj.add("Number", cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA)));

            cur.moveToNext();
        }
    }

    cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
            null);
    cur.moveToFirst();
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < cur.getCount(); i++) {
            mTempObj.add("Name", cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)));

            cur.moveToNext();
        }
    }

    cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, null);
    cur.moveToFirst();
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < cur.getCount(); i++) {
            mTempObj.add("Address", cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET)));
            mTempObj.add("City", cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY)));
            mTempObj.add("State", cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.REGION)));

            cur.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    mContacts.add(mTempObj);
}
```

it will solve your problem.

Comment: Can u please tell me if i need to find only the Mobile number of a particular contact name.Using the following fetches me all mobile number like work,Mobile,Home,Other.Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",new String[]{id}, null);while (pCur.moveToNext()){String phone = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));}pCur.close();

Comment: @Joyson Sorry but i don't know about this and put another question for that so it will help you more.

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
cursor.close();
cursor = null;
```

and make sure that the `contactId` that you passed to the `Cursor emails` is the same as the one that you retrieved from `Cursor cursor` which seems that you did not declare it in your  `String[] projection`

For the first projection you can as follow:

```
String[] projection = new String[] {
                ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME};
```

this projection will retrive the contact Id and contact name, then to get the contact id and Name

```
String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
 String Name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
```

Then the second projection could be somthing:

```
String[] projection2= new String[]{
                                 Email.ADDRESS,                 
                                 Email.TYPE
```

Then define second cursor to get email within the first cursor something like

```
Cursor cur2 = cr.query(emailURI,projection2,Email.CONTACT_ID + "=" +id,null,null);
```

where id is the id that you got from first cursor.

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks Husam could you please tell me what to add in projection array and fetch it.Currently i am using two different cursors.Thanks

Comment: I have to display the data  in a list view.If i use two different cursors how will i know which email corresponds to which name. since on the onclick of the row i will want to fetch the details of that particular row like first name ,last name,email address and phone number.

Comment: Thanks Husam will try it as you mentioned :)